# Using an image as a link in javascript with CSV data

Tags: javascript, csv

Apologies in advance if this is obvious- I'm new to js, and am learning it for a specific project.

I'm working on a database of information that needs to be 1) displayed as a table on a webpage and 2) able to be updated by a non-coding person by dropping a csv into a folder. I have gotten the images to display, and I can get links to work, but not combined.

Here's the version where I tried to combine them- I was hoping separating urls inside the csv's cells would let it read as two different links, but it ignores the non-image one.

```
        function format_link(link) {
            if (link)
                return "<a href='" + link + "' target='_blank'>" + "<img src='" + link + "' >" + "</a>";
            else return "";
        }


        CsvToHtmlTable.init({
            csv_path: "data/data.csv",
            element: "table-container",
            allow_download: false,
            csv_options: {
                separator: ",",
                delimiter: '"'
            },
            datatables_options: {
                paging: false
            },
            custom_formatting: [
                [0, format_link]
            ]
        });
```

Here's the original:

```
        function format_link(link) {
            if (link)
                return "<a href='" + link + "' target='_blank'>" + link + "</a>";
            else return "";
        }
        

        CsvToHtmlTable.init({
            csv_path: "data/data.csv",
            element: "table-container",
            allow_download: false,
            csv_options: {
                separator: ",",
                delimiter: '"'
            },
            datatables_options: {
                paging: false
            },
            custom_formatting: [
                [0, format_link]
            ]
        });
```

Any pointers would be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First mistake I'm noticing is how you're formatting the links. In HTML attributes always use double quotes. For example `<a href="your/url/here">A random link</a>`

In both the `a` and `img` tags above I'm noticing you're using single quotes when you should be using double quotes.

Try the following and let me know if it gets you any results:

```js
function format_link(link) {
    if (link)
        return '<a href="' + link + '" target="_blank">' + link + '</a>';
    else return "";
}
// OR
function format_link(link) {
    if (link)
        return '<a href="' + link + '" target="_blank"><img src="' + link + '" ></a>';
    else return "";
}
```

Also because it's relevant here, is the `CsvToHtmlTable.init` call custom code or is it a 3rd party library? I'm not familiar with all 5 million JS libraries, so I'd need to acquaint myself with it

Comment: Oops, I must've gotten mixed up there- thank you for pointing out the quotes. Unfortunately what you posted didn't work- it still only links to the image file itself, instead of the webpage that I need it to.

The library is a stripped down version of this: https://github.com/derekeder/csv-to-html-table - though now looking at it again, the error you pointed out is also there in the original files too.

Comment: That's progress at least! And OK that's my fault for confusing what the `link` variable represents. Ultimately what you need to do is find some way to pass 2 parameters to that `format_link()` function. One for the URL where the image is stored, and another for the url you want to link to. Easiest way to do that might be to store that first column as a pipe (|) delimited string. Do a string split on that to get the URLs.

You'll need to generate a link in the format `<a href="link/to/webpage" target="_blank"><img src="url/of/image"></img></a>`.

I hope this is more helpful for you.